# Light up Cicigarette/Cigar sfx

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

How do I make the match/lighter to cigarette sound where the flame and cigarette meet and the cigarette 'catches fire'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound designer Marek Domanski tweeted about this a while ago: Take your hair and scrape it with your fingers.

https://twitter.com/Marek_Domanski/status/537580471627296768?s=09

Comment: Thanks, what a great tip! I've been trying to figure out how to do this sound effect for a few days. Earlier today when I was making my ice coffee; I was slowly pouring the espresso over some ice and it also made a great sound of the hot espresso melting the ice cubes.